# I want to sumbit a form which have a drop down option using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to do some staffs. I am trying to submit a form using jQuery. Here is my code. Please take a look at them.

My aim is that when a user clicks on any drop down option the form will be submitted then. I have been searching for a long time but can't find solution of my specific problem. If you find this question similar to any other question asked please comment the link.

I am kinda new in jQuery. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="opart">
  <select name="sort_out" class="sort_tool">
    <option value="low-price">Sort Out Products By...</option>
    <option id="oparst" value="high-price">Price High to Low</option>
    <option value="low-price">Price Low to High</option>
    <option value="low-model">Model Name A-Z</option>
    <option value="high-model">Model Name Z-A</option>
    <option value="low-brand">Brand Name</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#oparst').click(function(){
    $('#opart').submit();
});
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)

Comment: I deleted 2 of the id "oparst" and kept one(I kept the id at prict high to low option). Then I run the code and clicked the option price high to low. But still no luck. Can you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done like this:

```
<select name="sort_out" class="sort_tool" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option> ... </option>
  <option> ... </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ID** should be unique.

Use `change` instead of using `click`.

```
$('#oparst').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == 'something'){
      $('form#opart').submit();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="opart">
 <select name="sort_out" class="sort_tool" id="chartName">
  <option id="oparst1" value="low-price">Sort Out Products By...</option>
  <option id="oparst2" value="high-price">Price High to Low</option>
  <option id="oparst3" value="low-price">Price Low to High</option>
  <option value="low-model">Model Name A-Z</option>
  <option value="high-model">Model Name Z-A</option>
  <option value="low-brand">Brand Name</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
 $("#chartName").click(function (e) {
    $('#opart').submit();
 });
});
```